# Unexpected iterator function and Iterable.take behavior

Tags: dart

I was writing a simple function called batches that should get an iterable split it to iterable of iterables of size size.
Then I ran into weird behavior of generator functions and Iterable.take method (when expecting/knowing python generators behavior).

this code:

```dart
Iterable<T> iterate<T>(Iterable<T> iterable) sync* {
  print('generator started');
  for (var item in iterable)
    yield item;
}

void main() {
  List l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  final it = iterate(l);
  print(it.take(2));
  print(it.take(2));
}
```

outputs:

```
generator started
(1, 2)
generator started
(1, 2)
```

while the expected output is:

```
generator started
(1, 2)
(3, 4)
```

1. Why does `iterate` is being called twice instead of continuing to the next iteration after the yield?
2. Any buildin or more elegant way of writing the following workaround?
   my workaround:

```dart
Iterable<List<T>> batches<T>(Iterable<T> iterable, int size) sync* {
  final iter = iterable.iterator;
  List group = takeN(iter, size).toList();
  while (group.length > 0){
    yield group;
    group = takeN(iter, size).toList();
  }
}


Iterable<T> takeN<T>(Iterator<T> iterator, int n) sync* {
  for (var i = 0; i < n && iterator.moveNext(); i++)
    yield iterator.current;
}


void main() {
  List l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  print(batches(l, 2));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how iterables and iterators work.

An `Iterable` is a simple object which does nothing until your start iterating.
An `Iterator` is the one maintaining the iteration state.

When you call a `sync*` function, it immediately returns an `Iterable`.
When you start iterating that iterable, by reading its `iterator` getter and using the returned `Iterator`, the `sync*` function body starts running. Every call to `moveNext` runs the body until the next `yield`.

Every time you get a new `iterator`, the function body starts from scratch.
That is why your two calls to `it.take(2)` both do the same thing, each work by getting a new iterator and calling `moveNext` twice.

As for an easier approach to what you want to do, maybe:

```dart
Iterable<List<T>> batch<T>(Iterable<T> source, int size) {
  List<T> accumulator;
  for (var value in source) {
    (accumulator ??= []).add(value);
    if (accumulator.length == size) {
      yield accumulator;
      accumulator = null;
    }
  }
  if (accumulator != null) yield accumulator;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
One thing that I still can't understand is why every access to it.iterator creates a new iterator instance, instead of one iterator instance that is the iterable attribute and holds it's state?

Comment: Each call to a method on `Iterable` is defined in terms of creating a new iterator, and they need to be separate. If you have a list, and you want to find the first element, and the last element, you would expect `var last = list.last, first = list.first;` to work. However, both are defined in terms of iterators (`List` inherits both getters from `Iterable`), so if each invocation of `iterator` did not give you a *new* iterator, but reused the previous (only?) iterator for the iterable, the `list.first` would be affected by the `list.last`.